# Import Spotify song request

Tags: python, spotify

I would like to connect to spotify API and connect with OAuth and then search for a song a user requests.

I currently have a bot pulling for youtube and saving the file to play. I was wondering if there a way to do the same with Spotipy.

```
from flask import Flask, request, url_for, session, redirect
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'xxx'
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_NAME'] = 'Token Cookie'

TOKEN_INFO = "token_info"

@app.route('/')
def login():
    sp_oauth = create_spotify_oauth()
    auth_url = sp_oauth.get_authorize_url()
    return redirect(auth_url)

@app.route('/redirect')
def redirectPage():
    sp_oauth = create_spotify_oauth()
    session.clear()
    code = request.args.get('code')
    token_info = sp_oauth.get_access_token(code)
    session[TOKEN_INFO] = token_info
    return redirect(url_for('getTracks', _external=True))

@app.route('/getTracks')
def getTracks():
    try:
        token_info = get_token()
    except:
        print("user not logged in)")
        redirect("/")
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth = token_info["access_token"])
    return 

def get_token():
    token_info = session.get(TOKEN_INFO, None)
    if not token_info:
        raise "execption"
    now = int(time.time())
    is_expired = token_info["expires_at"] - now < 60
    if (is_expired):
        sp_oauth = create_spotify_oauth()
        token_info = sp_oauth.refresh_access_token(token_info['refresh_token'])
    return token_info
    
def create_spotify_oauth():
    return SpotifyOAuth(
        client_id = 'CLIENT_ID',
        client_secret = 'CLIENT_SECRET',
        redirect_uri = url_for('redirectPage', _external = True),
        scope= 'user-library-read')
```

Comment: Are you asking about `getTracks`? You seem to be creating a Spotify client, but never use it. What difficulty are you having with it?

Comment: Yeah, so I'm confused on where to go from here, I would like to pull data from a txt file and search for those songs.

Comment: Then I would be able to pull data from discord, save it to a txt file, pull it through the spotify api and come back with a playable song?

Comment: Regardless of where you get the data, have you tried the search function? https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/#spotipy.client.Spotify.search